# SVG inverse marker mask/clip-path

Tags: svg

I've tried unsuccessfully to replace the white triangle, the `marker-start`, with an inverse mask/clip-path in order to cut the end of the arrow in shape of the marker instead of painting it white.
Not sure if marker masks can be defined.

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="mySVG" viewBox="-100 0 200 200" height="600" width="700">
    <defs>
  <marker refY="0.5" refX="0.0" markerHeight="4" markerWidth="2" orient="auto" id="head">
    <path fill="#D0D0D0" d="M0,0 L0.5,0.5 L0,1 L-0.5,0.5 Z"/>
  </marker>


  <marker refY="0.6" refX="0.1" markerHeight="4" markerWidth="2" orient="auto" id="tail">  
    <clip-Path id="cp1" d="M0 0 V1.3 L0.6 0.6 Z">
<path   fill="white" d="M0 0 V1.3 L0.6 0.6 Z"  />
    <clip-Path>
  </marker>   

</defs>

<path id="myArrow" marker-start="url(#tail)" marker-end="url(#head)" d="M -66.38265586443396 22.21132594835645 A 70 70 0 0 0 66.38265586443396 22.21132594835645" fill="none" stroke="#D0D0D0" stroke-width="8" clip-path="url(#cp1)"/>
```

Comment: I don't see any clip-path or mask code here...

Comment: As I told I don't know where and how to put it exactly. I tried defining a clip-path inside my second marker with the same value for "d" but it did not work. I edited the code now.

Comment: any solution you found ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Markers are independent symbols which are positioned and drawn at the various points in the path after the path has been drawn.

It sounds like you are trying to use them to clip out bits of the path.  This is futile.  That's not how markers work, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks. I see, so is there a way of clipping out bits a path then?

Comment: It will actually be a lot easier to use a mask for that.  Here is an example that should help: http://jsfiddle.net/tgw84/1/